Where to store self-signed certifiate private key in an electron app?
I am currently creating an electron app which basically runs a web server on the user's machine. When the user starts up the application, it generates a self-signed SSL certificate to be used to secure the communication. I want to persist this certificate so it is re-used every time the user opens the application.
My question is where do I store the certificate's private key? I know about safeStorage in electron, but I don't want to ask the user for a password every time they open the app
Any suggestions?
